# Sine of the sum of two solutions of $a\cos\theta + b \sin\theta = c$

Tags: functions, trigonometry, trigonometric-integrals

This is kind of a new type of question for me:

> If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are two different roots of the equation $a\cos\theta + b\sin\theta = c$, then show that
>
> $$\sin(\alpha+\beta) = \frac{2ab}{a^2 + b^2}$$

Could someone please explain the procedure to me?

Comment: Are you sure that it's true?

Comment: Well I'm pretty sure that this is true... unless my textbook is wrong.

Comment: this is not true, see my answer!

Answer (score 0):

write the equation in the form
$$\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\cos(\theta)+\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\sin(\theta)=\frac{c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$
and define $$\sin(\gamma)=\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$ and
$$\cos(\gamma)=\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$
and you will get
$$\cos(\gamma)\cos(\theta)+\sin(\gamma)\sin(\theta)=\frac{c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$
so $$\cos(\gamma-\theta)=\frac{c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$

Comment: You've introduced an $\alpha$ different from that in the question, what's the purpose of this?

Comment: i have changed it into $\gamma$

Comment: Sorry, but I still can't understand what you're trying to prove here...